# How to prevent the black screen on iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, screen

Is there a way to not let the iPod touch switch the screen off? I want to use my iPod as a "count down" timer with the built-in clock app. But after some time, the screen turns black thanks to the energy saver policy. I actually want to see the count down until the time is up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't got my iPod Touch with me but this works on the iPhone if you go to Settings -> General -> Auto-Lock and set it to Never. That should work.

Let me know if iPod Touch has removed this. Don't know why they would have!

Comment: Ok. I searched after "screen saver", but indeed, it's the autolock :-)